# How to know app was purchased in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have to implement in app purchase in my application, so I used below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html

Almost everything is working. But I have doubt that is how to know if `in app product` was purchased or not for particular device before purchase the app.

Because of my requirement is to show my `in app product` to purchase.

If particular device already purchased my `in app product` there is no need to show my `in app product`.

How can I know app is purchased or not before purchase the `in app product`?

Comment: Could you paste your code that isn't working, or are you just really confused on how to do it to the point that you aren't sure what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purchase information is stored in PurchaseDatabase class. From this class I am checking whether application was purchased or not.

For more information see this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-implement

Comment: is that possible to explain more where we can chuck item purchased??